# How to Stream screen without Broadcast Extension in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, streaming, replaykit

I wanna streaming my app to twitch, youtube or such a streaming service without any other application likes mob crush.

According to Apple, by using Broadcast Extension I can stream my application screen.
Broadcast Extension gave video data as a type of CMSampleBuffer. Then I should send that data to rtmp sever like youtube, twitch or etc.

I think if I can get video data, I can stream the other things without using Broadcast Extension in my app. So I try to send RPScreenRecorder data to rtmp server, but I doesn't work.

Here is a code I wrote.
I use HaishinKit open source framework to rtmp communication.
(https://github.com/shogo4405/HaishinKit.swift/tree/master/Examples/iOS/Screencast)

```
    let rpScreenRecorder : RPScreenRecorder = RPScreenRecorder.shared()
    private var broadcaster: RTMPBroadcaster = RTMPBroadcaster()

    rpScreenRecorder.startCapture(handler: { (cmSampleBuffer, rpSampleBufferType, error) in
        if (error != nil) {
            print("Error is occured \(error.debugDescription)")
        } else {

            if let description: CMVideoFormatDescription = CMSampleBufferGetFormatDescription(cmSampleBuffer) {
                let dimensions: CMVideoDimensions = CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions(description)
                self.broadcaster.stream.videoSettings = [
                    "width": dimensions.width,
                    "height": dimensions.height ,
                    "profileLevel": kVTProfileLevel_H264_Baseline_AutoLevel
                ]
            }
            self.broadcaster.appendSampleBuffer(cmSampleBuffer, withType: .video)

        }
    }) { (error) in
        if ( error != nil) {
            print ( "Error occured \(error.debugDescription)")
        } else {
            print ("Success")
        }
    }
}
```

If you have any solution, please answer me :)

Comment: @user2864740 My Question is possible screaming without Broadcast Extension. I can't understand why you change my title like that. It is totally different with what I want to ask.

Comment: Good job with a more appropriate title! (The original question title was "without 3rd application" and not "without Broadcast extension" - being precise is important!)

Answer (score 0):

I've tried a similar setup and it is possible to achieve what you'd like, just need to adjust it a little:

I don't see it in your example, but make sure that the broadcaster's endpoint is correctly set up. For example:

```
let endpointURL: String = "rtmps://live-api-s.facebook.com:443/rtmp/"
let streamName: String = "..."
self.broadcaster.streamName = streamName
self.broadcaster.connect(endpointURL, arguments: nil)
```

Then in the startCapture's handler block you need to filter by the buffer type to send the correct data to the stream. In this case you're only sending the video so we can ignore audio. (You can also find some examples with HaishinKit to send audio too.) For example:

```
RPScreenRecorder.shared().startCapture(handler: { (sampleBuffer, type, error) in
        if type == .video, broadcaster.connected {
            if let description: CMVideoFormatDescription = CMSampleBufferGetFormatDescription(sampleBuffer) {
              let dimensions: CMVideoDimensions = CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions(description)
               broadcaster.stream.videoSettings = [
                  .width: dimensions.width,
                  .height: dimensions.height ,
                  .profileLevel: kVTProfileLevel_H264_Baseline_AutoLevel
              ]
            }
            broadcaster.appendSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer, withType: .video)
        }
    }) { (error) in }
```

Also make sure that the screen is updated during streaming. I've noticed that if you're recording a static window with RPScreenRecorder, then it will only update the handler when there's actually new video data to send. For testing I've added a simple UISlider which will update the feed when you move it around.

I've tested it with Facebook Live and I think it should work with other RTMP services too.

Comment: If you can provide a sample code for fb live with replaykit would be great help for beginners.